# Why does session ID persist across sessions in PHP?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
    echo session_id();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

How come everytime I refresh this page it shows the same session id, even though the session gets destroyed and recreated each time?  Isn't the session id cleared upon session destruction?

**EDIT:**

I've used this updated code, based on the favorite answer- however, the session id STILL perists!  Any ideas?

```
if (!session_id())
        session_start();
echo session_id();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();


// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. **It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie.** To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

The manual comes with a code-example:

**Example #1 Destroying a session with $_SESSION**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

** Update **

**PHP Version 5.3.6-13**
Linux lime 3.0.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Wed Aug 17 04:28:34 UTC 2011 i686

**Apache/2.2.19 (Debian)**

**Session Settings (phpinfo)**

```
Directive           Local Value         Master Value
session.auto_start          Off         Off
session.bug_compat_42           Off         Off
session.bug_compat_warn         Off         Off
session.cache_expire            180         180
session.cache_limiter           nocache         nocache
session.cookie_domain           no value            no value
session.cookie_httponly         Off         Off
session.cookie_lifetime         0           0
session.cookie_path         /           /
session.cookie_secure           Off         Off
session.entropy_file            no value            no value
session.entropy_length          0           0
session.gc_divisor          1000            1000
session.gc_maxlifetime          1440            1440
session.gc_probability          0           0
session.hash_bits_per_character         5           5
session.hash_function           0           0
session.name            PHPSESSID           PHPSESSID
session.referer_check           no value            no value
session.save_handler            files           files
session.save_path           /var/lib/php5           /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler           php         php
session.use_cookies         On          On
session.use_only_cookies            On          On
session.use_trans_sid           0           0
```

**Update**

So. Following settings results in the same problem. if, and only if i'm sening the session id as a request parameter [locahost?PHPSESSID=whatever](http://localhost/?PHPSESSID=whatever)

```
ini_set('session.auto_start', 'on');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'on');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'off');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'off');

if(!session_id())
  session_start();

echo session_id();
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

**IMPORTANT:** 
this settings are valuable to Session Hijacking [[Session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)]

Comment: @maggie- I tried this, but did not work- please see my question edits above.

Comment: i've testet your code and the manual code example on my test server. new session id on each reload. see server details above

Answer (score 0):

It do not destroy your sessionID

so you'd use just

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
    session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: This is actually the problem described by the OP. That is the session id is persisting. How does your answer resolve that?

Comment: it does not check if session_id exists. Because session_destroy does not unset your session_id()

Comment: That doesn't matter. session_id() = "" before session_start is called.